# Inductive vs. recursive definitions

Tags: coq, inductive-type, soft-question

In Coq there are two ways to define a new type on an inductive type: Using `Inductive` and using `Fixpoint`. What are pros and cons of these approaches? Some aspects in which they can be compared: Difficulty of interacting with them (proofs, constructions). How large are the generated internal terms? Effects on performance.

Example:

```ml
Inductive list (A : Type) : Type :=
| nil : list | cons : A -> list -> list.

Inductive In {A : Type} (a : A) : list A -> Prop :=
| In_cons_hd (l : list A) : In (cons a l)
| In_cons_tl (hd : A) (tl : list A) : In tl -> In (hd :: tl).

Fixpoint In' {A : Type} (a : A) (l : list A) : Prop :=
  match l with
  | nil => False
  | cons hd tl =>
    a = hd \/ In' a tl
  end.

Theorem In_equiv (A : Type) (a : A) (l : list A) :
  In a l <-> In' a l.
```

If `Inductive` is used, one has to use the `destruct`, `induction`, `inversion` and `constructor` tactics (or explicitly choose a constructor using `apply`).
This makes it harder to write proof terms manually, I think.

If `Fixpoint` is used and (in the above example) the list starts with constructors, the computation will take care of these steps.

Sometimes the `Fixpoint` is not definable in Coq, because of issue [#1433](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/1433).

Edit: Using `Fixpoint` made more "primitive logical operations" (conj., disj., quantifiers) appear in my proofs, which `firstorder` could process and often solve quickly.

Edit 2, regarding `Fixpoint` being "strongly normalizing":
I think this is not that much of a problem per se, if enough disjunctions are used.
I see another difficulty with `Fixpoint`. The recursive property must be structurally (or well-founded) recursive in the data, for all possible input data. (Proven at the time of definition)

So for example a sequent calculus is "easily" definable using `Fixpoint` if it has the subformula property, or if we add a dummy natural number as "fuel", which must decrease when going up in the deduction tree. Calculi without subformula property probably can't be to translated directly from `Inductive` to `Fixpoint`.

Comment: As a small case study, in https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos595/stdlib/html/Coq.Lists.List.html while your `In` example is written using `Fixpoint`, the other two properties, `Permutation` and `NoDup` are written using `Induction`.

Answer (score 7):

Defining recursive properties by fixpoint is possible, but it is usually easier to reason on inductively defined ones. Mostly because they come with their own induction principles. If you use fixpoint then you are forced to use the inductive principles of the underlying data type (lists in your case). In your example it makes no difference but most of the time it does.

Moreover inductive relations allow to define much more relations than fixpoint because the use of recursion is not expected to define always terminating computations.

Comment: You seem to be implying that any predicate defined with `Fixpoint` is decidable. Is that really your intention?

Comment: Sorry that is not what I intended to say. Fixpoint must define some finite computation. In that sense they define something that can be computed. But the logical predicate resulting of this computation may be undecidable. I am not a specialist but I tend to recommend using inductive predicates in this case because the « computable » part is not very useful.

Comment: In that case, perhaps the last sentence of your answer can be deleted, as it is misleading as written. (And saying that "fixpoint must define some finite computation" isn't quite accurate, either. Fixpoints don't define "computations", they define elements of types, just like all other definitions in Coq. In the particular case when a fixpoint defines a function, that function is total and it therefore normalizes (computes) in finite number of steps – and that's what you likely meant, yes?)

Comment: I am not sure of what would be a fixpoint not defining a function. 

Would the following be correct?: Moreover inductive relations allow to define much more relations than fixpoint because the use of recursion is not expected to define always terminating computations. ”

Comment: Since you insist: fixed points are more general than inductive types because inductive types are a special case of fixed points.

Comment: I suppose this is not the place to discuss this but thanks for the insight. It seems to imply that any inductive type can be defined by a fixed point. But is it true in Coq?

Comment: Well, you could probably cook something up, but whatever you do, Coq will require evidence that the fixed point exists. For instance, consider `F (X) = unit + X`, it's initial algebra is `nat`. A naive recursive definition stating `Fixpoint nat' := unit + nat'` wont make Coq happy – it wants to know why this is well-defined. One should take inspiration from theorems about existence of initial algebras.

Answer (score 4):

Let me just mention a third possibility which is sometimes called "small inversion". This is some kind of middle ground between the two possibilities you present, which gives you some of the advantages of the Fixpoint-style definition on top of an Inductive-style one. Here is an example:

```
Definition In'' {A : Type} (a : A) (l : list A) : Prop :=
  match l with
  | nil => False
  | cons hd tl =>
    a = hd \/ In a tl
  end.

Theorem In_equiv (A : Type) (a : A) (l : list A) :
  In a l <-> In'' a l.
```

The main difference is that `In''` is *not* a fixpoint, because it does not call itself – only `In`. However, proving `In_equiv` is rather easy, and then applying it in an hypothesis/goal you can trigger just the amount of computation that the Fixpoint-based definition would give you. As the name "small inversion" suggest, this can be seen as an alternative, more controlled approach to inversion and the related tactics for indexed inductive types.

Answer (score 2):

`Inductive` allows you to express non-deterministic, non-terminating computations, while `Fixpoint` computations can be automatically reduced ("normalized") by [`cbv`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.cbv)/[`compute`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.compute) and [`cbn`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.cbn)/[`simpl`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.simpl).

A `Fixpoint` term is [**strongly normalizing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting)): for any fixpoint `f`, there's exactly one value which `f v0 v1 ...` reduces to, and you can get it with `cbv` or `compute` [3]. An `Inductive` term is not, which means there may be multiple ways to construct an instance `f v0 v1 ...`, or none at all, and you must find them manually with [`apply`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.apply)/[`constructor`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.constructor) (to construct the instance), [`inversion`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.inversion) (to reveal how the instance was constructed), and/or other tactics.

Repeating tactics on inductives [1] can also create loops and hang your Coq process [2]. For example, `repeat apply cons` if your goal is a list, or `repeat inversion` on a list hypothesis, will hang while generating the infinite term `(cons ?a (cons ?b (cons ?c ...`. `repeat cbv`, `repeat cbn`, `repeat compute`, and `repeat simpl` will never hang; in fact, when you call any of these tactics once, calling them again is guaranteed to do nothing.

Generally, you want to define a `Fixpoint` when it's easy enough to do so, and `Inductive` otherwise. Sometimes your computation is too complex to define in `Fixpoint` even when it's deterministic and guaranteed to terminate (specifically, when it uses non-structural recursion). In this case, you can either use `Program Fixpoint`, `Function`, or `Equations` (from [the coq-equations plugin](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/)), and then prove or just `Admit` the additional "obligations"; or you can use `Inductive` and you don't have to prove termination at all. Even when you can prove the obligations from `Program Fixpoint`/`Function`/`Equations`, those don't have as good UX as `Fixpoint`, and it may be easier to use `Inductive` when they are the only alternative.

There are also libraries like [ssreflect](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html) which try to achieve the best of both worlds for usability: you define both the `Inductive` and `Fixpoint` definitions of a computation, and can switch ("reflect") between them. Similarly, there may be a case where you have an intuitive `Inductive` definition and an unintuitive `Fixpoint` definition, and you want to prove they are equivalent (e.g. you are extracting `Fixpoint` definition and want it to match the `Inductive` specification).

---

[1] e.g. when using `Ltac` to try and automate constructing or "reducing" the inductive type

[2] Tip: when using coq with emacs and proof-general, use [`Set Default Timeout`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:opt.Default-Timeout) to prevent the process from permanently hanging and requiring you to restart `coqtop`

[3] Sometimes you *want* extra control like what you get by manually constructing/destructing inductives: sometimes the normal form you get via `cbv`/`compute` is too far reduced, and you must "undo" some of the computation via `change` (which is also manual) or other rewriting. This is where `cbn` and `simpl` come in, they're explicitly designed to prevent "bad" reductions and usually you want to use them instead of `cbv` or `compute`. When you need even more control, you can provide arguments to `cbn`/`simpl` or use `unfold`.

Comment: The example OP provided (`In`) is 'non-deterministic' and yet can be defined using `Fixpoint` so the distinction is not as strict as you make it to be.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can know, `Inductive` is used to define an inductive type, and `Fixpoint` a function on an inductive type.

Comment: This question asks about the intersection of the two cases where you are defining a function from an inductive type to a universe (usually `Prop`) that has both a natural `Inductive` type constructor definition and a natural `Fixpoint` definition.  (If you replace `Prop` with `Bool`, then `Fixpoint` would be the way to go of course.)